# Redux-form fileds type error: missing the following properties from type 'Props': fields, meta

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I have an error when use fields type, I use WrappedFieldArrayProps to define my props, but ts check error Type 'InjectedFormProps<{}, {}, string> & { children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': fields, meta.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, InjectedFormProps,  WrappedFieldArrayProps} from 'redux-form';
import { Form, FieldGroup } from '~/lamb';
import AlertRuleForm from './form_rule';
import AlertEmailForm from './form_email';
import t from '~/locale';
import FormFooter from '../FormFooter';
import { compose } from 'redux';

interface Props extends InjectedFormProps, WrappedFieldArrayProps {}

const connector = compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'AlertForm',
  }),
);

const UpdateAlertGroupForm = (props: Props) => {
    const { fields, handleSubmit, error } = props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form horizontal onSubmit={handleSubmit} formError={error}>
          {fields.getAll().includes('name') && (
            <Field
              component={FieldGroup}
              name="name"
              type="text"
              label="alert_name"
              placeholder="Please input alert name"
              required
            />
          )}
          {fields.getAll().includes('alertRules') && <AlertRuleForm />}
          {fields.getAll().includes('emailGroupIds') && <AlertEmailForm />}
          <FormFooter {...props} />
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
};

export default connector(UpdateAlertGroupForm) // error from here;
```

And error

Argument of type '(props: Props) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType>'.
  Type '(props: Props) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'InjectedFormProps<{}, {}, string> & { children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': fields, metats(2345)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Props extends Partial<InjectedFormProps>, WrappedFieldArrayProps {}
```

Comment: Please, explain your solution